# Return an IDisposable helper object for cleaning up

Tags: c#, idisposable

I'm currently designing a class `Device` that has two states: *Opened* and *Closed*.

In *closed* state, only basic readonly operations are allowed, like `GetName()` or `GetID()`.
In *opened* state, the user can modify the device, e.g. with `SetPropertyX(int value)`.

The Device can be *opened* with the function `Open()` and *closed* with the function `Close()`, which should be called by the user in any case once he is done with configuration.

I'm thinking of a nice way to use the IDisposable interface in this case. The goal is that the Device is automatically *closed* when a using block is left.

Basically I see 2 options:

#### 1) `Device` implements the IDisposable interface

Device class:

```
class Device : IDisposable
{
    public void Open();
    public void Close();
    public string GetName();
    public void SetPropertyX(int value);
    public void Dispose(); // will call Close() if device is open
}
```

User app:

```
using (Device device = new Device())
{
    device.Open();
    device.SetPropertyX(42);
} // implicit device.Close()
```

In this case, the `device` object is of type `IDisposable`, but the `Dispose()` function is only effective when the user has called `Open()` before. I feel like this is not a proper usage of the `IDisposable` interface, because usually objects of type `IDisposable` are ready to use right away, without the need for further initalization (in this case calling `Open()`).

#### 2) `Open()` returns a helper object of type IDisposable

Helper class:

```
internal class DisposeHelper : IDisposable
{
    private Device m_dev;
    public DisposeHelper(Device d)
    {
        m_dev = d;
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        m_dev.Close();
    }
}
```

Device class:

```
class Device
{
    public IDisposable Open();
    public void Close();
    public string GetName();
    public void SetPropertyX(int value);
}
```

User app:

```
Device device = new Device();
using (device.Open()) // no need to store the returned object in a variable
{
    device.SetPropertyX(42);
} // implicit Close() by helper
```

In this case, the `IDisposable` object is only used for making sure that `Close()` is called at the end of the using scope and thus we don't need to store the object in a variable. But again, I have a feeling that this isn't a proper usage of the `IDisposable` interface either.

Any ideas how I can achive my goal (use `using` to make sure that the device is closed)?

Comment: `IDisposable` isn't ment for arbitrary open/close-mechanics, but for getting rid of unmanaged resources, which the garbage-collector cannot handle. Having said this you can just use a `try/finally`-block for this instead.

Comment: `SqlConnection` is `IDisposable` but if you won't open the connection then there probably isn't anything to dispose, but you would always put it in a `using` block just to be safe.

Comment: Btw.: why do you specifically want a `using`-statement? What's the purpose of this? You need to indicate the enclosing scope either way. With a `using` you just have a single block-statement, though.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain That is how it was supposed to be used yes. But even Microsoft uses it for arbitrary reasons to make the code cleaner (see `BeginForm`/`MvcForm` in ASP.NET for example)

Comment: Surely Device should be split into e.g. DeviceDetails and OpenDevice, the latter of which is returned by `Open` and allows the operations that only make sense on an open device, and is disposable. Meanwhile DeviceDetails supports the operations that make sense always and just Open, not Close.

Comment: You would be best to split  the device class into several interfaces and have a factory to create the devices. Here's an example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/tUb4jv

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain True, but it's been abused before like that, see eg Serilog's `LogContext.PushProperty`.